# Associate all the filenames at different paths along with their time interval in Unix

Tags: bash, shell

I have multiple files (with .txt or .ext format) at different directories.
The files path is stored in a variable say var.

I want to pick all the filenames as well the time interval (in hours) since the file was last placed.
The time interval will be current time - the last modification time.
Let's say

```
The file is at /Files/New directory with below time :
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ad.sam unx_9998_access         0 Nov  9 08:43 out.txt
```

I want the file name i.e out.txt and the interval ( in hrs) together.
This want to do for all the files in different paths (in the var variable).
So expected output is :

```
out.txt,12
abc.txt,9
pqr.txt,7
```

I am able to pull those details separately in different variables like below:

```
Files_in_Path=`ls -ltr | awk '{ print $9 }'`
TIMEDIFF=echo $(( ($(date +%s) - $(stat $Files_in_Path  -c %Y)) / 3600 ))
```

But I am not able to associate it together like filename,interval for all the files.

Comment: I don't see how your approach of handling the file pathes could deal with file names which habe a space in them. Also, why are you requesting a long listing of `ls`, and then extract only the 9th field, instead of simply listing the file names only. Also, your usage of `stat` assumes that you get a number of a **single** file (because you subtract it from a number), while `Files_inPath` is a string holding many file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what your expected output is.  If it's enough to print the file name and its age side by side, try

```sh
now=$(date +%s)
for file in ./*; do
    then=$(stat "$file" -c '%Y')
    printf '%s,%i\n' "$file" $(( (now - then) / 3600))
done
```

Notice also how we [don't use `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and more tangentially that

```
TIMEDIFF=echo $((1))
```

doesn't actually assign the evaluated value of `$((1))` to `TIMEDIFF` -- instead, it temporarily assigns the string `echo` to `TIMEDIFF` and attempts to evaluate the value as a command (so you would get a `1: command not found` unless you happen to have a command whose name is `1`).

Comment: The output of `stat` is system-dependent, but if you are on Linux, `%Y` is seconds and dividing that by 3600 gets you hours, yes.  The wildcard `./*` matches all files, use a different wildcard like `./*.txt */.ext` if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks Much. One more question:
I am storing all the different file paths in a variable as below:
FilePath=$(cat file_details.csv | awk -F "," '{ print $2 }' | tail --lines=+1 )
How do I incorporate this in the for loop below in the "in" clause?
file in ./*[.txt,.ext];

Comment: That's not a valid wildcard for what you say you want (it means `./*[,.etx]`after you remove the duplicate characters).  Bash allows `./*.{txt,ext}` but it doesn't really save you much over the portable and IMHO more readable equivalent.

Comment: Like i want to check in all the paths which is inside the variable and only the file types .txt and .ext

Comment: I don't see a variable. This expands to all the `*.txt` and `*.ext` files in the current directory.  Maybe you mean `./**/*.{txt,ext}` to also traverse subdirectories.

Comment: I have defined a variable like below
FilePath=$(cat file_details.csv | awk -F "," '{ print $2 }' | tail --lines=+1 )
This variable stores all the different file paths from where we have to pick the filename and age information. The current script picks filename and age from current directory only

Comment: To read paths from a file, try `awk -F "," 'NR>1 { print $2 }' file_details.csv | while IFS= read -r file; do`...

Comment: But really, at this point, probably (accept this answer, or post one of your own and accept that, and) ask a new question with your *actual* requirements spelled out in plain sight.